# CXF - com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Illegal character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 5))

Tags: spring, cxf, illegal-characters

I found on internet that problem is that soap request contain unicode char for ,,ctrl + v", which is illegal character in Xml. I dont know how this get into String, but I want simple to remove it on server side.

Can plase someone give me the point how to solve this issue?
I found this snippet :

```
  XMLOutputFactory f = new WstxOutputFactory();
  f.setProperty(WstxOutputProperties.P_OUTPUT_INVALID_CHAR_HANDLER,
    new InvalidCharHandler.ReplacingHandler(' '));
  XMLStreamWriter sw = f.createXMLStreamWriter(...);
```

Can someone tell me how to configure Spring for construction of WstxOutputFactory with this handler? - **InvalidCharHandler.ReplacingHandler(' ')**. Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution is pretty simple :

```
    <jaxws:endpoint id="kservice"  
                    implementor="#kostrounService"
                    address="/call_kostroun" >
                    <jaxws:properties>
                           <entry key="javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory"            valueref="xmlOutputFactory" />
                     </jaxws:properties>       
    </jaxws:endpoint> 
 <bean id="invalidCharHandler"   class="com.ctc.wstx.api.InvalidCharHandler$ReplacingHandler">
         <constructor-arg value=" "/>
   </bean>

   <bean id="xmlOutputFactory" class="com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxOutputFactory"/>

   <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
        <property name="targetObject">
            <ref local="xmlOutputFactory" />
        </property>
        <property name="targetMethod">
            <value>setProperty</value>
        </property>
        <property name="arguments">
            <list>
                 <util:constant static-field="com.ctc.wstx.api.WstxOutputProperties.P_OUTPUT_INVALID_CHAR_HANDLER"/>
                 <ref bean="invalidCharHandler" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

This snippet of configuration remove illegal characters from soap message, and app then run ;-)