# Illegal character entity: expansion character (code 0xe

Tags: java, cxf, special-characters

I am using CXF to connect the SOAP web service. Some times while requesting the server i am getting **Illegal character entity: expansion character code 0xe** exception.

I found that due to illegal character in Xml this exception occurs. Also i found the solution for this

```
  XMLOutputFactory f = new WstxOutputFactory();
  f.setProperty(WstxOutputProperties.P_OUTPUT_INVALID_CHAR_HANDLER,
    new InvalidCharHandler.ReplacingHandler(' '));
  XMLStreamWriter sw = f.createXMLStreamWriter(...);
```

But i dont know how to apply this in CXF. Can someone tell me where i have to use this code in CXF.Thanks in advice.

Comment: There are interfaces like MessageBodyReaders and Writers. I am sure CXF must have some plugabble option by which you can specify your messagebodywriter. This message body writer can have your custom code

Answer (score 5):

You could use an incoming interceptor on the server or and outgoing on the client and clean the xml before the unmarshalling occurs.

**Incoming Phases**

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|Phase                    | Functions                                        |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|RECEIVE                  | Transport level processing                       |
|(PRE/USER/POST)_STREAM   | Stream level processing/transformations          |
|READ |                   | This is where header reading typically occurs    |
|(PRE/USER/POST)_PROTOCOL | Protocol processing, such as JAX-WS SOAP handlers|
|UNMARSHAL                | Unmarshalling of the request                     |
|(PRE/USER/POST)_LOGICAL  | Processing of the umarshalled request            |
|PRE_INVOKE               | Pre invocation actions                           |
|INVOKE                   | Invocation of the service                        |
|POST_INVOKE              | Invocation of the outgoing chain if there is one |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Outgoing Phases**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|Phase                    | Functions                                                 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|SETUP                    | Any set up for the following phases                       |
|(PRE/USER/POST)_LOGICAL  | Processing of objects about to marshalled                 |
|PREPARE_SEND             | Opening of the connection                                 |
|PRE_STREAM               |                                                           |
|PRE_PROTOCOL             | Misc protocol actions                                     |
|WRITE                    | Writing of the protocol message, such as the SOAP Envelope|
|MARSHAL                  | Marshalling of the objects                                |
|(USER/POST)_PROTOCOL     | Processing of the protocol message                        |
|(USER/POST)_STREAM       | Processing of the byte level message                      |
|SEND                     |                                                           |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Keep in mind that you will have to do it before unmarshaling (incoming) or after marshalling (outgoing).

[Here](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/interceptors.html) you can find all the details, plus the necessary examples for using inteceptors.

**Update**

After some more research I've found these:

1. [Solution with spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12061766/cxf-com-ctc-wstx-exc-wstxunexpectedcharexception-illegal-character-ctrl-cha)
2. [Solution without spring](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/cxf-users/201110.mbox/%3CCAF8t5XsKkRtM4DzKgHqEUd186BXQEpWGOokm-8Y2uGy95AdLGg@mail.gmail.com%3E)

Copy and paste from the second link (the first is SO answer)

```
package tmp;

public class MyWstxOutputFatory extends WstxOutputFactory {
    public MyWstxOutputFatory() {
        setProperty(com.ctc.wstx.api.WstxOutputProperties.P_OUTPUT_INVALID_CHAR_HANDLER,
                    new
com.ctc.wstx.api.InvalidCharHandler.ReplacingHandler(' '));
    }
}
```

and use it in your jaxws configuration

```
   <bean id="outStaxFactory" class="tmp.MyWstxOutputFatory"/>

   <!-- jaxws:client or server -->
       ...
       <jaxws:properties>
           <entry key="javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory">
               <ref bean="outStaxFactory"/>
           </entry>
       </jaxws:properties>
       ...
```

Comment: No problem with the downvote, but at least give an explanation.